# What can we implement using native WebRTC in iOS? How much approx. time it will take in Screen sharing, Audio, Video and Text Chat implemetaion?

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, video, webrtc

I want to develop a `native iOS` app using `WebRTC` that have almost similar functionality to **skype**. I have few queries :

- Q 1) I know we can implement `Audio` and `Video` call using `WebRTC` but is
  it possible to implement Text Chat and Screen Sharing in iOS app
  using `native WebRTC` ?
- Q 2) I need to provide time estimation of **`Audio Call`,`Video Call`,
  `Group Audio call`, `Group Video call`, `single user text(share media as well) chatting`, `multi user text (share media as well) chatting` and
  `Screen Sharing`.

Please let me know approx. development time of individual functionality if single developer works on it, who have good hands in `iOS development`.

Thank you....:)

Comment: did you find answer?

Comment: I stopped work on this app. I did not find answer.